# How to interpret long equations in Deep Learning papers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder, bayesian

For eg. I've been studying a paper on Recommender systems using collaborative deep learning and I've just started learning.

The paper revolves around the NN representation as shown below
[image: Graphical model of cdl]

[image: A two layer sdae]

The hierarchical models.

[image: collaborative deep learning]

[image: generalized bayesian sdae]

Having the main optimization problem
[image: optimization problem]

Need help interpreting it. 
Here is a link to the original paper:
http://www.wanghao.in/paper/KDD15_CDL.pdf

Comment: All ML at the core needs linear algebra and matrix manipulation. So the easiest way is the hard one.

Comment: @KiriteeGak True. I've done the basics but some guidance would help me with the study of the system